# Mechanize page.search based on adjacent tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, mechanize

I need to scrape a page which doesn't have many classes defined which would allow me to group information together.

This shows what I'm trying to scrape:

```html
<h2 class="header">
    <a class="header" href="index.php?id=45>Product 1</a>
</h2>
<p>There are no active items attached to this product.</p>

<h2 class="header">
    <a class="header" href="index.php?id=43">Product 2</a>
</h2>

<table class="description_header" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> ... </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="subbar"></div>

<table class="tablehandler_list" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> Col 1 </td>
            <th> Col 2 </td>
            <th> Col 3 </td>
            <th> Col 4 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Info 1 </td>
            <td> Info 2 </td>
            <td> Info 3 </td>
            <td> Info 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have product headers with nothing under them and product headers with data associated with them.

I use Rails 4 with mongoid and the goal is to create a hash with the above data like so:

```
{"Product" => "Product 1"}  
{"Product" => "Product 2", "Col 1" => "Info 1", "Col 2" => "Info 2", "Col 3" => "Info 3"}
```

I though the CSS adjacent sibling selector could help me, and it does help find the right headers but it only returns the second tag. If I use

```
page.search("h2.header + p")
```

it will only give me the `<p>` tags and I would like to know the product as well from the `h2.header`.

Is there a method which gives me the next tag on the same level? This way I could look for headers with `page.search("h2.header")`, for example, and check tags that follow.

Comment: Nokogiri's documentation explains it all, especially the "[Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node)" docs.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found this and much more in Nokogiri docs some time ago. After reading all this my question seems rather silly. I'll post a simplified answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my problem was that I was googling for an answer to my question with reference to Mechanise rather than Nokogiri.

A very simplified version of my solution is as follows:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
products = Hash.new
products["Products"] = {}
headers = Array.new
tmp_prods = Hash.new
h2 = doc.xpath('//h2[@class="header"]').reject {|i| i.next.name == "p"}
h2.map do |e|
    products["Products"][e.text] = {}
    e.next.next.next.xpath('./tbody/tr/th').map {|th| headers.push( th.text.strip ) }
    e.next.next.next.xpath('./tbody/tr/td').map.with_index {|td, index| tmp_prods[headers[index]] = td.text.strip }
    products["Products"][e.text].merge!(tmp_prods)
end
```

and I end with with a hash:

> products
>    => {"Products"=>{"Product 2"=>{"Col 1"=>"Info 1", "Col 2"=>"Info 2", "Col 3"=>"Info 3", "Col 4"=>"Info 4"}}}